# FragmentManager is already executing transactions. While using fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Iam using a Viewpager inside a fragment.** And the viewpager is initialized after the fragment is created. The viewpager has two tabs.
But while i am setting the adapter for the viewpager "**FragmentManager is already executing transactions**." this error comes up.

Error is as follows.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lalrentals.app.lalrentals, PID: 26248
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: **FragmentManager is already executing transactions**

Java class :

```
public class HomeFr extends Fragment
{

    public HomeFr(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //ADDING VIEWPAGER
        ViewPager viewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFr(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new PostAddFr(), "Post");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        //SETTING TAB FOR THE VIEWPAGER
        TabLayout tabLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.frag_home,null);
        return v;
    }

    //ADAPTER FOR THE VIEWPAGER
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: improve your formatting and explain good way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this is the root cause but I think following point is wrong:

```
adapter.addFragment(new HomeFr(), "Home");
adapter.addFragment(new PostAddFr(), "Post");
```

Inside `HomeFr` fragment you are adding `HomeFr` again. Instead, you should have a "generic" `Fragment` which will host `HomeFr` and `PostAddFr`.

So, in the end, you should have 3 fragments:

1. `Host` which will be the parent `Fragment` and this fragment is responsible to instantiate the view pager
2. `HomeFr` one of the Fragments displayed by the view pager
3. `PostAddFr` one of the Fragments displayed by the view pager

Something like:

**HostFr**

```
public class HostFr extends Fragment {

    public HostFr(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFr(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new PostAddFr(), "Post");
        ....
    }
    .....
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ....
    }
}
```

**HomeFr**

```
public class HomeFr extends Fragment {
    ...
    // HomeFr Views
    ...
}
```

**PostAddFr**

```
public class PostAddFr extends Fragment {
    ...
    // PostAddFr Views
    ...
}
```